# How to add Pre Filter in Spring cloud gateway

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using spring cloud gateway to route request to my downstream application
I have the router defined something like below

```
@Configuration
public class SpringCloudConfig {

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route(r -> r.path("/user/test/**")
                        .uri("http://localhost:8081/test")
                        .id("testModule"))
                .build();
    }

}
```

Routing works fine, now I need to add a prefilter  which can do some pre-condition and get routing path.   but not getting how to change uri dynamically .uri("http://localhost:8081/test")

Below is the code I am trying for out in preFilter.

```
   @Component
public class testPreFilter extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory {

    
    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        System.out.println("inside testPreFilter.apply method");
        
        return (exchange, chain) -> {
         //get headers and do lookup for URI in mapping DB 

          **//If contains return modify the uri** 
            return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(request).build());
          //else 401 
        };
    }
    
}
```

so I need to forward from incoming path **/user/test/**** to http://localhost:8081/**test1** or http://localhost:8081/**test2** based on db lookup return in my custom filter

Comment: pre filters are based on the filter API which has a filter chain and reactor return types. anything before the filter chain is a pre filter. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/71014d10bfa040a08d3479b161b79b3c8cd0d4a8/spring-cloud-gateway-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/filter/factory/AddRequestHeaderGatewayFilterFactory.java#L38-L43

Comment: post filter example here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/71014d10bfa040a08d3479b161b79b3c8cd0d4a8/spring-cloud-gateway-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/filter/factory/RemoveResponseHeaderGatewayFilterFactory.java#L51

Comment: thanks, I could add my custom filter but got stuck at adding different uri, for incoming path /user/test/** to http://localhost:8081/test1 or http://localhost:8081/test2 based on db lookup return in my custom filter. it is getting replaced with same due to uri("http://localhost:8081/test") in my gatewayRoutes

Comment: I facing the same problem,:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69249075/why-the-spring-gateway-filter-did-not-trigger @kcoder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically changing the path I believe , so you can do that in [this](https://youtu.be/puIJ1Mn9_LE?t=867) fashion .

Based on the value you get from the database , set the path .