# why the spring gateway filter did not trigger

Tags: java, spring

I define a filter in my spring gateway(`2.2.8.RELEASE`) project like this:

```
@Component
public class LogFilter2 extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory {
    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Object config) {
        return (exchange,chain) -> {
            System.out.println("LogFilter2 flitered!!!");
            return chain.filter(exchange);
        };
    }
}
```

then config the filter in `application.properties` like this:

```
# dolphin music
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lower-case-service-id=true
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=dolphin-music-service
# forward by ip:port way
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=http://10.107.64.246:11014
# forward by service name way
# spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/music/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0]=LogFilter2
```

but when I run the project and send a request to the url `/music/xxxxxx`, the request did not enter the filter.No log `LogFilter2 flitered!!!` output.what should I do to make the filter works as expect? I also tried many other way,this is the minimal demo:https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/java-learn. In this demo, I define different kind of gateway filter, no one work except the global gateway filter. I am struggle with this problem for days.